# "Holla at your girl" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference, phrases

What does "holla at your girl" mean exactly? and what is the difference between that and "holla at your boy"? Does it depend on the gender of the speaker? Also, how is "holla" pronounced?

It was used at the end of an email by a co-worker (female) which was sent to the team saying "Any questions, holla at your girl."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean *holler*? *Hola* is "hello" in some languages. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Do any of the people involved like rap music, or use other features of American black slang?

Comment: Not sure. They are Australian actually :)

Comment: @Maryam, the context you provided in comments really makes a difference - please consider making an [edit] to incorporate that information into the question.  Thanks!

Comment: It simply means "call me"
In this instance, "call your girl", (your friend)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **holla**

is being used in place of **holler**, just as

> *holla* -> holler
>   *wanna* -> want to
>   *gonna* -> going to

A common express is

> just *give me a holler*

meaning

> contact me

usually (implicitly meaning) with some question

In your example, she is calling *herself*

> your girl

in an informal, slangy sort of way.

Comment: There is a duet song *Holla, Holla* by Akon and T-Pain. In this song, there is a sentence repeatedly comes, *Let me holla at you girl.* So would that mean *let me call you my girl*?

Comment: I think you're basically right, but the comparison with `wanna` and `gonna` is flawed, as this isn't a contraction of two words (with elision) in the same way.  It's just phonetically marking the non-rhotic `r`, and so more similar to spellings such as `rockin'` or `huntin' an' fishin'`.

Comment: @AJ No, it means 'Can I call you sometime' which indirectly probably means 'Can we hook up sometime'.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "holla" is pronounced like the word "hall", followed by "uh".  The emphasis is on the first syllable.  "Holla" rhymes with "impala".

Comment: They do not rhyme for everybody... I do not pronounce the [ɑː] of [ɪmˈpɑːlə] in _hall_ or _holla_.

Comment: That's three different vowels here: /hɒlə/, /hɔːl/, and /ɪmˈpɑːlə/.

Comment: @oerkelens There's no vowels left if you don't pronounce the a in hall...?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I didn't say I did not pronounce the _a_ in _hall_, but I certainly do _not_ pronounce it as /ɑː/.

Comment: Personally I'd say *holla* rhymes with *impala*, but I've heard "impala" pronounced two different ways. Maybe a less ambiguous rhyming word is koala.

Comment: @cjl750 "Koala" is just as bad cause it's the same vowel as "impala": [ɑː] as in PALM. Although you're right, "impala" has an alternate pronunciation with [æ] like in TRAP. The problem is that these words are pronounced differently between American and British/Australian accents. For you in the US and me in Canada, we have the father-bother and cot-caught mergers, so "impala", "holla", and "hall" all have the same vowel.